# Can I use jQuery to append specific post data with the post's thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Disclaimer: I'm a general newb all around but especially in regard to JS & jQuery - I am, in fact, working my way through the cadecademy JS course right now.

Background: I've been trying to figure out how to append specific data from within a post on a WP site below the post's thumbnail (the thumbnail is displayed using the List Category Posts plugin) which is displayed on the top level page, not within the post itself, and I've been considering one of two ways to do it:

1) Use the custom field display within the List Category Posts plugin
2) Use jQuery to fetch & append the data below the post's thumbnail, something like this but it will have to fetch unique data each time, reliably, which will be specific to each post:

```
 <script>
 jQuery("#content > article > header > .entry-title").append("<hr />");
 </script>
```

The field is constant in each post as an id (#static_field). I'm sure there's a pretty solid way to do this but I'm not sure how to do this, yet.  Can I specify where to get the data for each post in place of the horizontal row in my code?

As always, any & all help/constructive criticism is appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to explain deeper what you are trying to achieve, I am not following you.

Comment: Okiedoke - there are posts that are made on this WP site that are pulled by the LCP plugin & placed on a given page & I'd like to be able to append one line, a date (not the post date), under the thumbnail that the plugin displays.
Since this is a production site, I'm reluctant to play with it too much, especially since there are massive portions of the site that rely on the LCP plugin.  
The plugin lays out how to display/filter by custom fields but I'm even greener on my PHP.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level:

1. You need to setup a WP endpoint to return the data you need. Usually, this would go in `functions.php` and look something like:

   ```
   //setup hooks
   add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_cb'); 
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_cb'); // non logged in users

   function my_action_cb() {
         // pull in global
         global $wpdb;

         // grab sanitized get id value
         $post_id = filter_var($_GET['post_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

         $data = array();              
         //grab the data you need from the db and save to data

         echo json_encode($data); // json_encode the data

         wp_die(); // bail

   }
   ```

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

1b. Localize your wp_ajax_url. Still in functions.php:

```
    wp_localize_script( some_handle, 'admin_url', array('ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

2. Then for each post on the page, get the post_id and make an ajax request

   ```
   (function($){

        //grab all the articles on this page
        // loop over them and make an ajax call with the post id
        $(SOMESLECTOR).each(function() {
             var article = $(this);
             // get post_id from somehwhere
             makeAjaxRequest(post_id).then(function(resp) {
                 // resp is a JS object that should contain whatever data you echoed in php
                 article.find('.entry-title').append(/** Append you data here **/);
             });

        });

        function makeAjaxRequest(postId) {
              return $.ajax({
                   url: admin_url.ajax_url,
                   data: {
                       action: my_action, // same thing provided wp_ajax_<action>
                       post_id: postId
                   }
              })
        }


   })(jQuery);
   ```

Note:

This is MUCH more work and more overhead than just jumping into the WP template files and grabbing the data within the loop.

Comment: It seems like we may need to find another way!